# flask.g referenced before assignment only in some endpoints

Tags: python, rest, flask

Hi I have a quite weird problem. I'm using Flask 0.10.1 and i'm setting some info in `g` in the `before_request`.
However in exactly two of my endpoints (no decorators, nothing special apparently) fail referencing `g` with a `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'g' referenced before assignment` error, if in the debugger console i print `g` everything is there...
Also if i place a `from flask import g` inside the endpoint, everything goes ok.
Any clue of what could it be?

Bonus question: is `flask.g` still a good place to save data that must be unique to the current request?(thread safe, other requests safe ecc...)

Please help! Thanks

Comment: I ran into this issue when there was a `for g in list_of_things` loop deeper down into the route function.

Answer (score 0):

It was a very hard one to describe here without posting the entire codebase.. It came out it was related to weird import conflicts (as usual in python :D). Instead of importing `g` directly i used `flask.g` in my calls and everything got solved.

Thanks for the support